# how to match two data frames and retrieve matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, rows

I need to compare two data frames using pandas and retrieve matching rows. I need to compare on the basis of both Sr.No and ID. My data frame is in three columns as you can see. Its not working with merge (gives an empty dataframe).
here are my sample dataframes:

```
    df1:
    Sr.No| ID | Translation
    1    |1   |My name is Nisa
    2    |3   |My name is Nadia
    2    |4   |My name is Madiha

    df2:
    Sr.No|ID|Translation
    1    |2 |مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ
    2    |3 |اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيم
    2    |4 |الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
    3    |1 |بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
My output should be like this:
df3:
Sr.No|ID|Translation
 2   |3 |اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيم
 2   |4 |الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
```

Comment: Heard of a merge? `df1.merge(df2, on=['Sr.No', 'ID'])`

Comment: its not working with merge..it gives an empty dataframe with merge as well.

Comment: Did you specify the subset of columns? See my comment.

Comment: still it is giving this: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Sr.No, ID, Translation_x, Translation_y]
Index: []

Comment: Then try `df1 = df1.astype(df2.dtypes.to_dict())` and then merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need same dtypes of columns for join, you can check it by:

```
print (df1[['Sr.No', 'ID']].dtypes)
print (df2[['Sr.No', 'ID']].dtypes)
```

And then for all `int` or all `str` columns:

```
df1[['Sr.No', 'ID']] = df1[['Sr.No', 'ID']].astype(int)
df2[['Sr.No', 'ID']] = df2[['Sr.No', 'ID']].astype(int)
```

---

```
df1[['Sr.No', 'ID']] = df1[['Sr.No', 'ID']].astype(str)
df2[['Sr.No', 'ID']] = df2[['Sr.No', 'ID']].astype(str)
```

Then merge works very nice:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['Sr.No', 'ID'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1

   Sr.No  ID        Translation
0      1   1    My name is Nisa
1      2   3   My name is Nadia
2      2   4  My name is Madiha

df2

   Sr.No  ID                            Translation
0      1   2                مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ
1      2   3      اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيم
2      2   4                 الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
3      3   1  بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
```

---

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['Sr.No', 'ID'])

   Sr.No  ID      Translation_x                      Translation_y
0      2   3   My name is Nadia  اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيم
1      2   4  My name is Madiha             الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
```

Please check the datatypes of your columns and ensure they are the same, as jezrael mentioned. You can do:

```
df1 = df1.astype(df2.dtypes.to_dict())
```

---

If you don't want the first `Translation`, call `drop` first.

```
df1.drop('Translation', 1).merge(df2, on=['Sr.No', 'ID'])

   Sr.No  ID                        Translation
0      2   3  اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيم
1      2   4             الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ
```

Comment: 35 days more to become "legendary" ! :-)

Comment: @MaxU Cheers, I couldn't have gotten this far without your support. B)

Comment: I can say the same... :)

Comment: @Nisa remember, always accept the most helpful answer.